# PHP SQL grouping all columns with same starttime

Tags: php, sql

So i am having trouble coding the SQL queries correctly to get the desired output.

```
    <body class="hi">

    <div class="container dt[-head|-body]-center">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="table">
                <hr>
                <table style="width:100%" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:20%">ID</th>
                            <th style="width:15%">Date / Time</th>
                            <th style="width:15%">Location </th>
                            <th style="width:15%">Team A</th>
                            <th style="width:15%">Team B</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">Score A</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">Score B</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                        <?php
                           $sql = 
                           "SELECT * FROM activitytable WHERE starttime IN
                           (
                               SELECT starttime FROM activitytable 
                               GROUP BY starttime HAVING count(*) > 1
                           )"; 
                           $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['starttime'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['location'] ?></td>

                            <?php
                            if ($row['team'] = 1) 
                            {
                            ?>

                            <td>
                            <?php
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                            }
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            if ($row['team'] = 2) 
                            {
                            ?>
                            <td>

                            <?php
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo $row["person"];
                                echo "<br>";
                            }
                            ?>
                            </td>
               
                            <td><?= $row['team'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['scoreA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['scoreB'] ?></td>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It needs to be grouped by `starttime`. when I exec the code above it doesn't group the `startime`, it creates a row for every person and it is just printing every persons name 4 teams in each row.

Team A and Team B columns need to get the players from either team 1 (Team A) or 2 (Team B)

So in the database will be 8 records for every game played.

id - AUTO INCREMENT
player - players name
starttime - time of activity
scoreA - score for team 1
team - either 1 or 2
scoreB - score for team 2
location - location activity was held.

I want the output to look like this. Can't seem to figure it out, new to `PHP` `SQL`.

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

u must use two separate query for achieving this :

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct starttime FROM activitytable" ;
$res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
    $sql = "SELECT player FROM activitytable WHERE starttime = '" . $row['starttime '] . "'";
    $players = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    // rest of your html code
}
```

and then :

```
<td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['starttime'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['location'] ?></td>
<?php
if ($row['team'] = 1) 
   { ?>
       <td>
       <?php foreach($players as $player) {
           echo $player["player"];
           echo "<br>";
       }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\testing.php on line 105

Comment: so what settled is in line 105 of testing.php ?!?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT players FROM activitytable WHERE starttime = $row['starttime']";

Comment: plz try it again

Comment: there is no query fetching all the other columns

Comment: SO is a place for getting hints and figuring out programming bugs, not a community of full-code writers that have to guess questioner probable bugs. if you need help you need to try harder and explain more. not only by saying there is a bug in line 105 or there is no query for all columns. besides all of that, $res_data contains all distinct times and second query will get all players that have the time. then print them, this will fetch all columns.